# Google Spreadsheet script add 5 days to cell

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I've tried to write a script that would add 5 days to cell A1 in Google Spreadsheets. I have no clue what to do to gain the result. Could somebody guide me how to create such script?

Comment: did you try anything at all?

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to tell what you want exactly but to add days to a date you just do:  =A1+5